# Multi Login ZF2 with multi session

Tags: authentication, zend-framework2, zend-db, zend-auth

I have an application with 3 different logins (3 different dashboard). Not to write duplicate code I created an adapter and a plugin to login.

Now how can I manage 3 different sessions. If I run in to login Login 1 must also be signed on dashboard 2 dashboard 3, but only on dashboard 1.

How can I handle this? multi session for multi login.

Comment: It would make more sense to use a single login, but use Zend ACL to restrict the access and only show the user the options they have access too.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with authentication (or login: know what the identity of the user is) but *authorization* (or access: has the user the right to access this page).

You should not manage authorization with different logins, different sessions and so on. Just use a single identity for a user and use authorization for access. Take an example with ACL or RBAC, both inside `Zend\Permission`.

With these permission systems, you can say: this user X is allowed to access dashboard 1 and 3. The user Y is allowed to access 1 and 2. The user Z is only allowed to visit dashboard 1.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Zend\Permissions\Acl. Check section "Multiple Inheritance among Roles".
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.permissions.acl.intro.html

```
use Zend\Permissions\Acl\Acl;
use Zend\Permissions\Acl\Role\GenericRole as Role;
use Zend\Permissions\Acl\Resource\GenericResource as Resource;

$acl = new Acl();

$acl->addRole(new Role('guest'))
    ->addRole(new Role('member'))
    ->addRole(new Role('admin'));

$parents = array('guest', 'member', 'admin');
$acl->addRole(new Role('someUser'), $parents);

$acl->addResource(new Resource('someResource'));

$acl->deny('guest', 'someResource');
$acl->allow('member', 'someResource');

echo $acl->isAllowed('someUser', 'someResource') ? 'allowed' : 'denied';
```

But in case you don't want to use ACL. then why don't you add into your login table a permission column an integer(1,2,3...up to 7 I think) on login add this integer to a session and on each dashboard you check for permission number if not allowed access then you redirect to login or home page.

Comment: I can not use id saved in the table, because the log are also different in the tables.
One serves to administer the website (cms) and the other login servers to handle the user (user profile).